# Worker timeout when preloading Pytorch model in Flask app on Render.com

Tags: python, flask, pytorch, gunicorn

In my app.py I have a function that uses a pretrained Pytorch model to generate keywords

```
@app.route('/get_keywords')
def get_keywords():
    generated_keywords = ml_controller.generate_keywords()
    return jsonify(keywords=generated_keywords)
```

and in ml_controller.py I have

```
def generate_keywords():
    model = load_keywords_model()
    output = model.generate()
    return output
```

This is working fine. Calls to /get_keywords correctly return the generated keywords. However this solution is quite slow since the model gets loaded on each call. Hence **I tried to load the model just once by moving it outside my function**:

```
model = load_keywords_model()

def generate_keywords():
    output = model.generate()
    return output
```

**But now all calls to /get_keywords time out when I deploy my app to Render.com.** (Locally it's working.) Strangely the problem is not that the model does not get loaded. When I write

```
model = load_keywords_model()
testOutput = model.generate()
print(testOutput)

def generate_keywords():
    output = model.generate()
    return output
```

a bunch of keywords are generated when I boot gunicorn. Also, all other endpoints that don't call ml_controller.generate_keywords() work without problems.

For testing purposes I also added a dummy function to ml_controller.py that I can call without problems

```
def dummy_string():
    return "dummy string"
```

Based on answers to similar problems I found, I'm starting Gunicorn with

```
gunicorn app:app --timeout 740 --preload --log-level debug
```

and in app.py I'm using

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False, threaded=False)
```

However, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's some bug that occurs for Pytorch models when Gunicorn is started with the `--preload` flag.

Render.com secretly adds this flag and doesn't show it in the settings which is why it took me days to figure this out. You can see all settings Render.com adds by calling `printenv` in the console.

To resolve the issue add a new environment variable

```
  GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS: '--access-logfile - --bind=0.0.0.0:10000'
```

which overwrites Render.com's standard settings

```
  GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS: '--preload --access-logfile - --bind=0.0.0.0:10000'
```